# SQL Server function returns question marks instead of real result

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8

I have this function which retrieves first word from String:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FIRST_WORD(@value nvarchar(1000))
RETURNS nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1)
       WHEN 0
         THEN @value
       ELSE SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) - 1) END
 END
GO
```

The problem is the data in my table is in `non-ASCII` format, so when i pass some value to that function, i get question marks instead of a result:

`SELECT dbo.FIRST_WORD('ничего не поделаешь')`

returns: `??????`

But if i pass `ASCII` characters, for example:

`SELECT dbo.FIRST_WORD('hello world')`

it returns: `hello` as expected.

I tried to add `N` before the argument, but it didn't help:

`SELECT dbo.FIRST_WORD(N'ничего не поделаешь')`

still returns: `??????`

Comment: @marc_s dude, read the question carefully. `I tried to add N before the argument, but it didn't help:

SELECT IMPORT_DATA.FIRST_WORD(N'ничего не поделаешь')`

Comment: @marc_s He said that he has already tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov can't you change your database collation?

Comment: @iminiki No, i can't do anything with database configuration, i'm not db admin.

Comment: This function returns first word as expected, the question has wrong information. The function is created in dbo schema, the called function is in import_data schema. I tried it 1 minute fa and it works correctly with cyrillic passed as unicode (with N )

Comment: Database collation is irrelevant here, the function works with unicode. It is sufficient to pass string as unicode

Comment: @sepupic Yes, it's just a typo. The problem is still exists

Comment: I am trying to simulate your issue but there is no any problem `SELECT dbo.FIRST_WORD(N'ничего не поделаешь')` resut `ничего`

Comment: @Vijunav Vastivch So why mine not working? :(

Comment: The only problem if dont have an `N` on the first value like `SELECT dbo.FIRST_WORD('ничего не поделаешь')`

Comment: I have a version `10.50.4000.0`  and server Collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues

1. Required **Select** Keyword
2. Required **N** while sending Unicode data.
3. The return statement will be proper

This is you need :

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.FIRST_WORD (@value nvarchar(max))
 RETURNS nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

 Return (Select CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1)
   WHEN 0
     THEN @value
   ELSE SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) - 1) END)

 END
GO 

Select dbo.FIRST_WORD(N'ничего не поделаешь')
```